# increment operator within conditional operator in c

Tags: c

I expected b to be 3.
is this an undefined behavior?
or the result could be predicted?
but i thought b would be 3.
and c would be 2. 
the output i got is 1 2 1
please explain

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int a = 0;
int b = 1;
int c = (a++ >b++ )? a++ : b++;
printf("%d %d %d",a,b,c);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: b is 3, and c is 2.. what compiler did you use?

Comment: @Weston pelles c.i got 1 2 1 as output.

Comment: Please uninstall that compiler ASAP!

Answer (score 4):

That's what I get, and I agree it's guaranteed to be that.  There is a sequence point after evaluating the first operand (the condition) before going to the second or third operand.  So it goes like this:

```
(a++ >b++ )
```

evaluates to:

```
0 > 1
```

which is 0.

After that, `a` is 1 and `b` is 2.

Since it was false:

```
b++
```

is evaluated.  The result is 2 (which is assigned to `c`), and afterwards `b` is 3.

If that's the exact code, your compiler is buggy.  It's not even a question of order.  Even if the third operand were evaluated before the first (which would be wrong), `b` should still be 3.

I am using GCC 4.6.3, but the result will be the same in all standards-compliant compilers.

Answer (score 2):

It's defined behavior, there's a sequence point between the first operand of `?:` and second or third one.

So after evaluating `a++ < b++`, a = 1 and b = 2. Then the third operand gets selected. Thus c gets assigned `b++`. So c = 2 and *then* b = 3.

The C11 standard says:

> 6.5.15  Conditional operator
>
> The ﬁrst operand is evaluated; there is a sequence point between its
>   evaluation and the evaluation of the second or third operand
>   (whichever is evaluated).

Comment: @cdummy Yes, that's clear from the question. That means your compiler is broken.